# How can I delete or manipulate the clipboard history?

Tags: command-line, copy-paste

I can read the clipboard history on the «Raycast» app which is a very useful replacement for Apple's Spotlight, but I am not able to delete / manipulate the clipboard history.

I have tried some more apps from the Mac App Store: CopyClip, Paste, Alfred; none of them can delete / change the clipboard history.

In addition I couldn't find a shell command which is able to even read the clipboard history which is a bit weird.

I am looking forward to some hints.

Comment: The history is going to be a property of each app. The Mac itself doesn't keep a history.

Comment: What @Tetsujin said.   You need to get a Clipboard Manager.  I use FlyCut for this.

Comment: Alfred has a clipboard history aw well, as probably the other apps the OP tried.

Comment: You can "manipulate" entries in Raycast clipboard history. Under Actions (⌘+K) there are several "manipulation" actions including "Delete Entry", "Delete Entries", "Delete All Entries", "Pin Entry" etc along with associated keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: ah, what a mess, Raycast is really the solution for me, as I have it instally already. Many many thanks